# Slow performance when creating empty arrays of specific sizes in different browsers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm noticing peculiar performance stats for creating empty arrays using `Array(length)` in Chrome (85), Firefox(79), and Safari(11.1) on a Mac OS X (10.13.4) system.

Here's my test script;

```
console.time('Array(length)');
var len_int = 1;
var test_arr = Array(len_int);
console.timeEnd('Array(length)');
console.log('test_arr.length =', test_arr.length);
```

I'm trying various `len_int` from 1 to 1000000000 [one billion]. Here are the stats I'm getting:

**CHROME**

```
Array(length) - 1: 0.018310546875 ms
Array(length) - 10: 0.014892578125 ms
Array(length) - 100: 0.01171875 ms
Array(length) - 1000: 0.0068359375 ms
Array(length) - 10000: 0.011962890625 ms
Array(length) - 100000: 0.187744140625 ms
Array(length) - 1000000: 1.826904296875 ms
Array(length) - 10000000: 18.211181640625 ms
Array(length) - 100000000: 0.026123046875 ms
Array(length) - 1000000000: 0.0126953125 ms
```

**FIREFOX**

```
Array(length) - 1: 1ms - timer ended
Array(length) - 10: 1ms - timer ended
Array(length) - 100: 0ms - timer ended
Array(length) - 1000: 0ms - timer ended
Array(length) - 10000: 2ms - timer ended
Array(length) - 100000: 1ms - timer ended
Array(length) - 1000000: 0ms - timer ended
Array(length) - 10000000: 0ms - timer ended
Array(length) - 100000000: 1ms - timer ended
Array(length) - 1000000000: 1ms - timer ended
```

**SAFARI**

```
Array(length) - 1: 0.006ms
Array(length) - 10: 0.028ms
Array(length) - 100: 0.011ms
Array(length) - 1000: 0.009ms
Array(length) - 10000: 0.031ms
Array(length) - 100000: 0.252ms
Array(length) - 1000000: 1.663ms
Array(length) - 10000000: 19.373ms
Array(length) - 100000000: 696.767ms
Array(length) - 1000000000: 0.008ms
```

What is peculiar is that Chrome breaks sub-millisecond performance for 1000000 [1.8ms] and 10000000 [18ms], and then drops back below sub-millisecond for higher arrays. Safari is somewhat worse on performance from 1000000 [19ms] to 100000000 [696ms], and then it drops at 1000000000 [0.008ms]. Firefox appears to be fairly consistent on performance.

Why this anomaly? Is there are fix or alternative approach to doing the same thing without losing the performance edge?

I should point out that I've run this benchmark multiple times and see this anomaly each time. I also ran it on an iPhone 7 with Safari (via BrowserStack) and witnessed the same anomaly.

I ask because I'm using `Array(length)` to speed up a few scripts that leverage arrays, but the performance gains are gone on Chrome and Safari for arrays that are sized between 1000000 and 10000000.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on microbenchmarks with just a single run, as the errors are too great because of other running processes and compiler optimizations.

At the very least, you should let the code run a large number of times and make sure that the array is actually used so that the compiler cannot optimize it away.

Comment: Thanks. I did run the benchmark multiple times. I'll mention that in the edit of the question.